# Get specific type from List<CustomModel> using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this part of the method:

```
var t = typeof(T);
var fieldValues = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var typesToCast = new List<string>();
var fieldsToCast = new List<string>();

foreach (var field in fieldValues)
{
    var attr = (MetaAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaAttribute), false);
    if (attr.Length > 0)
    {
        fieldsToCast.Add(field.Name.ToString());
        typesToCast.Add(field.PropertyType.Name);
    }
}
```

But, if I have a property like:

```
public MyModel something {get;set;}
```

The result of

```
field.PropertyType.Name
```

is `MyModel`

But, I have  `public List<MyModel> something {get;set;}`
how I can get the `MyModel` type using reflection for a `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the first type argument of a type. You can get it with:

```
if (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
{
    var typeArguments = field.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
    typesToCast.Add(typeArguments[0].Name);
}
else
{
    typesToCast.Add(field.PropertyType.Name);
}
```